# Using OFFSET with a 3D range (range across multiple sheets)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, average, offset

I have a database with the relevant data in the same rows across several sheets, with data in every other column. I have been trying to use 3D ranges with AVERAGE/SUM and OFFSET but I can't seem to figure it out. I am getting a #VALUE error during the OFFSET part. Here is the setup I have been using.

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET('Sheet 1:Sheet 4'!A1,0,COLUMN(A1)*2-1))
```

The sheet names do have spaces in them so the space in my above formula between the word Sheet and the number is intentional. I have tried the 3D range with just the average/sum functions and it works fine. Are the 3D ranges not compatible with the OFFSET function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
=AVERAGE(N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&{"Sheet1","Sheet2"}&"'!A1"),0,COLUMN(A1)*2-1)))
```

or

```
=AVERAGE(N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&$G$2:$G$3&"'!A1"),0,COLUMN(A1)*2-1)))
```

...where G2:G3 contains the sheet names.  Note that the second formula needs to be confirmed with `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER`, not just `ENTER`.

Hope this helps!

**FIRST EDIT**

While an array formula is still required, you can avoid having to confirm the formula with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and you can avoid having to list your sheet names in a range of cells.

1)  First define the name `SheetNames` as follows...

```
Refers to:  ={"Instrument Partners","Supply Partners","Repair Partners","Wholesale Partners"}
```

2) Then try...

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&SheetNames&"'!A1"),0,COLUMN(A1)*2-2)),0))
```

...which only needs to be confirmed with `ENTER`.

**SECOND EDIT**

`"'"&SheetNames&"'!A1"` returns the following array of text values...

```
"'Instrument Partners'!A1"
"'Supply Partners'!A1"
etc...
```

This array of text values is passed to INDIRECT, which returns the following array of references...

```
'Instrument Partners'!A1
'Supply Partners'!A1
etc...
```

In turn, this array of references is passed to OFFSET, which also returns an array of references based on the row and column offsets...

```
OFFSET('Instrument Partners'!A1,0,COLUMN(A1)*2-2) --> 'Instrument Partners'!A1
OFFSET('Supply Partners'!A1,0,COLUMN(A1)*2-2) --> 'Supply Partners'!A1
etc...
```

Then we retrieve the values by passing this array of references to the N() function...

```
N('Instrument Partners'!A1) --> returns actual value from the cell reference
N('Supply Partners'!A1) --> returns actual value from the cell reference
etc...
```

Then we pass this array of values to the INDEX function, which returns an array of values and allows the formula to be confirmed with just ENTER, instead of CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Lastly, the array of values is passed to the AVERAGE function, which returns the actual average.

Comment: Thanks! I tried both formulas and the result was 0 when it should have been 50, so I went into the evaluate and it seems that I still get a #VALUE error along the way.I think I should have mentioned a few more things about the sheet layout. The sheets all have spaces in the names and this cannot be changed. Also, there are 4 sheets (all in order) that need to be referenced so my original should have said something like 'Sheet 1:Sheet 4'

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that! You were right, the cell I was referencing was off by a row. However, both formulas seem to only take the average of just the values on Sheet 1 and Sheet 4, missing the two in between. Sorry, I know I didn't specify this in the original question but there are more than two sheets to reference. This current solution requires 4 but there can be up to 15-20 sheets so I would like if there is a way to refer to the first and last sheets in the formula and obtain info from all the sheets in between.

Comment: Since you have quite a number of sheets, use the second formula.  Simply enter your sheet names in a range of cells, and replace G2:G3 with a reference to the range containing your sheet names.  Also, make sure that you confirm the formula with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, not just ENTER.  Just to be sure, though, which cells do you want to average?

Comment: Ah that does work properly with the array formula, thank you so much! Is there anyway you can think of that this can be done without the array formula or without adding the list of sheet names in other cells? I can see somewhere down the line this info being copied and pasted without the range containing sheet names so it may not transfer over properly. If this is not possible then no worries.

Comment: Instead of dragging the formula across so that every cell will contain an average, can you drag or paste it so that every **other** cell will contain the average?  If not, what are your sheet names?

Comment: I need it so that every cell that I drag across contains an average since it has to match the information above it which also uses offsets. The specific sheet names are 'Instrument Partners', 'Supply Partners', 'Repair Partners' and 'Wholesale Partners' .

Comment: Hmm there is still an issue with your edited response, it looks like when I input ={"Instrument Partners","Supply Partners","Repair Partners","Wholesale Partners"} into a cell and hit enter, only Instrument Partners appears so when it is referred to in the formula it does not work. Your original array solution fits my needs perfectly so I will stick with that. Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Actually, you don't input it into a cell, you define a name.  On the Ribbon, go to the Formulas tab, and in the Defined Names group, click on Define Name.  Then enter the name being defined, which in this case is `SheetNames`, and then enter `={"Instrument Partners", ...}` in the `Refers to` box.

Comment: THAT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH! For future reference, are you able to let me know how exactly to follow the logic of the formula? I would like to understand how it is working so hopefully I can make changes on my own in the future if required.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks again!